# Creating a new layer from raster attribute table in R with terra?

Tags: raster, r, terra

Say I have a raster with a raster attribute table:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("whateverfilepath.tif")
rat <- levels(r)
```

I would like to create a new layer based upon a value from the raster attribute table. I am currently doing that via `classify()`:

```
rcl <- matrix(c(rat$Value, rat$FieldOfInterest), ncol=2)
newr <- classify(r, rcl)
```

It seems like there has to be a faster way? I expect this will succeed, but the reclassification is taking a lonnnng time (55 thousand row RAT, and thus 55 thousand row reclassification table).

Effectively, looking for something similar to the ArcGIS [lookup tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/lookup.htm) in terra.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Feeding the categories obtained via `levels()` to `classify()` does not make sense and also would not work since `rcl` would consist of characters, and you would need an integer matrix. You probably would have noticed with the upper example being reproducible. Have a look at `?terra::classify` for some examples. However, what is your goal? Assuming you had a SpatRaster object witth n categories, do you want to extract category x (let's say, forest areas) to a new object? And 55,000 rows in `rat` sounds very suspicous and not correct, by the way.